# Masonry-rails not working

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add in Masonry-rails/gem in my app. add in gem, JavaScript, and necessary function, but now do not works masonry successfully.

So this time. I want to help you.

- First Bundle install  => "gem 'masonry-rails'"
- Second Include CSS/application.scss => below application.js
- Third Include application.js => //= require masonry/jquery.masonry
- forth Write code pins.js.coffee => below pins.js.coffee
- fifth Write view => below index.html.erb

application.js

```
 *= require 'masonry/basic'
 *= require 'masonry/centered'
 *= require 'masonry/fluid'
 *= require 'masonry/gutters'
 *= require 'masonry/infinitescroll'
 *= require 'masonry/right-to-left'
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
```

pins.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#pins').imagesLoaded
    $('#pins').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url(:medium)) %>
      <h1><%= link_to pin.title, pin_path(pin.id) %></h1>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= paginate @pins %>
```

I want solve this problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to tell us what is wrong. You cannot simply give us the code.